# use of すんな and ってもんがある

Tags: colloquial-language, contractions

It's a male character saying thing this

> 抜け駆けすんなっ、まずは順序ってもんがあるだろ

"Don't get a head start, first of all, there is a proper order of doing things" (?)

Is すんな = the negative imperative するな?

Is ってもんがあるだろ = というものがあるだろ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a level of "slang"-iness being used in this sentence. Allow me to rewrite in a way that might be more clear:

抜け駆け**しないで**、まずは順序って**もの**がある**だろう**

すんな < するな < しないで

もん < もの

だろ < だろう

Also, as an aside:

「順序」ってもの = "A thing called an order"

Comment: Turning するな into しないで is too much. するな is already perfectly "standard" and you don't have to change it into a much milder request.

Comment: I know that するな is a standard expression. I thought it resourceful for those who browse the question and haven't learned this expression yet